# $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+ax^2+a^2x+a^3}},\text{with } x(0)=x_0>>a, x(T)=a.$ Find an approximation of $T$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

So at $x(0)=x_0$ we have:

$\frac{dx(0)}{dt}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0^3+ax_0^2+a^2x_0+a^3}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0^3}}   $ and so $\sqrt{x_0^3}dx(0)=dt$

And at $x(T)=a$ we have:

$\frac{dx(T)}{dt}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4a^3}} $ and so $\sqrt{4a^3}dx(T)=dt   $

I'm not sure how we can combine this information to get an approximation of $\int_0^Tdt$ (or indeed if using this information is necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

Close to your function:
$$(x+a)^3=(x+a)(x^2+2ax+a^2)=x^3+3ax^2+3a^2x+a^3$$
But the exact factorisation is:
$$x^3+ax^2+a^2x+a^3=(x+a)(x^2+a^2)$$
this tells us that:
$$x'(-a)\to\infty$$
so there is a vertical asymptote as $t=-a$. Also as you said we know that $x'(0)\approx x_0^{-3/2}$. Since the derivative has no other real zeros we can assume that the function $x(t)=0$ has no solutions for $t>0$ and so one way to approximate would be linearly:
$$x(T)=x(0)+x'(0)T$$
$$a\approx x_0+x_0^{-3/2}T$$
giving:
$$T\approx\frac{a-x_0}{x_0^{-3/2}}=x_0^{3/2}(a-x_0)$$